# SpagoBI multi value parameter

Tags: java, parameters, birt, spagobi

I'm trying to create a multi-value parameter in SpagoBI.

Here is my data set query whose last line appears to be causing an issue.

```
select C."CUSTOMERNAME", C."CITY", D."YEAR", P."NAME"
from "CUSTOMER" C, "DAY" D, "PRODUCT" P, "TRANSACTIONS" T
where C."CUSTOMERID" = T."CUSTOMERID"
and D."DAYID" = T."DAYID"
and P."PRODUCTID" = T."PRODUCTID"
and _CITY_
```

I created before open script in my dataset which looks like this:

```
this.queryText = this.queryText.replace(_CITY_, " CUSTOMER.CITY in ( "+params["cp"].value+" ) ");
```

My parameter is set as string, display type dynamic list box.

When I run the report I'm getting that error.

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: There are errors evaluating script "
this.queryText = this.queryText.replace(_CITY_, " CUSTOMER.CITY in ( "+params["cp"].value+" ) "); 
":
Fail to execute script in function __bm_beforeOpen(). Source:
```

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Where did you run the report?? In spagobi server or studio? or..??

Comment: In studio. I solved this problem. I had to pass "?" as a first element of my list box string array, then the rest of the elements. I have never seen example like this. Now I have the problem with deploying my report to server. **The type of parameter "CITYPARAM" is expected as "Object[]", not "java.lang.String".** I guess the problem is that my parameter in studio is set as list box. I don't know how to do this with text box, because typical replacing in beforeOpen script isn't working. The "?" in my querry is necessary. I'm glad You are here marc_s

Comment: yes you are correct. it's because of parameter type.
change parameter type to String. in beforeOpen script, try
`this.queryText = this.queryText+" and CUSTOMER.CITY in (" + params["cp"].toString().replace(";", ",") + ")"` this worked for me.

Comment: @su_bhagya is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I managed to solve the problem. Here is my code:

```
var substring = "" ;
var strParamValsSelected=reportContext.getParameterValue("citytext");
substring += "?," + strParamValsSelected ;
this.queryText = this.queryText.replace("'xxx'",substring);
```

As You can see the "?" is necessary before my parameter. Maybe It will help somebody. Thank You so much for Your comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **SpagoBI server** and **High charts** (JFreeChart Engine) / JSChat Engine you can just use ($P{param_url}) in query,
or build dynamic query using Java script / groovy Script

so your query could also be:

```
select C."CUSTOMERNAME", C."CITY", D."YEAR", P."NAME"
from "CUSTOMER" C, "DAY" D, "PRODUCT" P, "TRANSACTIONS" T
where C."CUSTOMERID" = T."CUSTOMERID"
and D."DAYID" = T."DAYID"
and P."PRODUCTID" = T."PRODUCTID"
and CUSTOMER."CITY" in ('$P{param_url}')
```