# SpagoBI OLAP multivalue parameter MDX

Tags: parameters, mdx, olap, spagobi

I am creating the OLAP report with parameter. I have selected my data set as my parameter's default value. So when I am executing my report, all parameter values are checked. My query looks like this.

```
select NON EMPTY {{[Measures].[VALUE]}} ON COLUMNS,
  NON EMPTY {{[CUSTOMER].[COUNTRY].Members}} ON ROWS
from [TRANSACTIONS]
where [DAY].[${param}]
```

My integer parameter is setting [DAY].[YEAR], delivering it in this form **;{value1;value2}NUMBER}**.
I am getting that error :

> Unexpected character ';'

This character is between values of my delivered parameter . How to solve this problem? I can't do something like this in query `where [DAY].[2015,2016]`
Best regards!

Comment: don't think this is valid MDX `[CUSTOMER].[COUNTRY] in (${param})`

Comment: Right, I changed I bit my query and parameter, look at the update, I coundnt have dimension on more than one axis.

Comment: you need to provide it as a set: `{[DAY].[2015],[DAY].[2016]}`

Comment: Would You like to give me an answer? I am pretty fresh with reporting tools. I ll try my best.

Comment: For reporting are you using reporting-services?

Comment: I am using SpagoBI, my OLAP runs on jpivot engine

Comment: can you use the logic from your previous answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588099/spagobi-multi-value-parameter

Comment: Why do You think so? I think I can't, because I can't  handle the case, when parameter isn't set. This logic ensures me that parameter is set everytime. User can uncheck redundant parameter values.

Answer (score 0):

Never used SpagoBI so this is based only on the [Wiki](http://wiki.spagobi.org/xwiki/bin/view/spagobi_server/data_set#HParametersandProfileAttributes):

> $P{< name of the parameter >(prefix;split_char;suffix)}

```
select NON EMPTY {{[Measures].[VALUE]}} ON COLUMNS,
  NON EMPTY {{[CUSTOMER].[COUNTRY].Members}} ON ROWS
from [TRANSACTIONS]
where {${param([DAY].[;,;])}}
```

Comment: I think this should be use in data set which has sql syntax, not in MDX

Comment: @mxix will strToSet be important? guess that is more for MS orientated mdx?

Comment: @whytheq no idea! Never used SpagoBI, but looking at the examples this is concatenated at run-time. Just like Doing Split(Join()) logic within SSRS. Concatenates first executes late. But it's me just guessing.

Comment: I went round in circles with a parameter question for LucasPG back here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033405/spagobi-olap-report-passing-optional-parameter